# how to use spring data rest with multiple boot apps

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, spring-data-jdbc

I have two aggregate roots, Account which holds id, name and Alert which holds id, title and Account(@ManyToOne). Using spring boot with data-jpa and data-rest I can see the full magic in swagger-ui.
Now I want to achieve the same result while breaking it into two boot apps each one holds one aggregate root with its own DB. Can someone please share an example, guidance or anything that can help me do it the right way. If preferred I can use data-jdbc instead of data-jpa. 10x